# How to health check if ActiveMQ is working properly in asp.net core?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, activemq-classic, asp.net-core-6.0, health-check

How do you check the health of the ActiveMQ service?

```
public async Task<HealthCheckResult> CheckHealthAsync(HealthCheckContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
    {

        // Health Check ActiveMq Code?
        
        return HealthCheckResult.Healthy();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A best practice is to send a message and receive it. This verifies *everything* -- SSL, authentication, authorization, etc.

Especially, if you have a cluster. You can send one message to broker 1 of the cluster and consume it from broker 2 in the cluster.

Answer (score 0):

Writing an an approach for a similar health check mechanism for future readers.
I recently implemented a health check for message broker and here is what I did:-

- After any message is successfully processed by the message broker, push a log to azure app insights.
- Create an alert on top of the logs pushed to app insights saying that if there are no logs in the last (n)minutes then send an email to the dev team saying that the messages are not being processed for some reason and the service is unhealthy.